# Код выдает Segmentation Fault, почему?

Tags: c++, boost, boost.asio

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/asio.hpp>
#include<boost/array.hpp>

using tcp=boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(),9999);
    tcp::acceptor accept(io_service,endpoint);
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    accept.accept(socket);
    std::string message="Hello";
    int readedByte=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        int readByte=socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(&message+readedByte,sizeof(message)));
        readedByte=readedByte+readByte;
        if(readedByte==sizeof(message))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Это код сервера

А вот код клиента кидает Segmentation fault

```
#include<boost/asio.hpp>
#include<boost/array.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using tcp=boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::endpoint endpoint;
    endpoint.port(9999);
    endpoint.address(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("127.0.0.1"));
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    socket.connect(endpoint);
    std::string req{""};
    int readedByte=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        int readByte=socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(&req+readedByte,128));
        readedByte=readedByte+readByte;
        if(readedByte==sizeof(std::string{"Hello"}))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

В чем дело?

Comment: Неправильные аргументы в конструкторе `asio::buffer` Первым должен идти указатель на буфер, вторым - его размер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прерывание  поднимается из-за того, что `&req+readedByte` указывает на нелегальную область памяти. `&req` -  это указатель на объект типа `string`, `&req+readedByte` - указатель на `readedByte`-й элемент массива `string`-ов,следующий за `&req`. Такого масива тут нет. `&message+readedByte` тоже нелегален, но тут серверу "повезло".

Указывать на сам класс сторки нельзя - это не та область памяти, где хранятся данные (обычно там внутри есть указатель на реальный буфер). К тому же строку нельзя использовать для записи напрямую, для этого следует воспользоваться чем-то похожим на вектор как промежуточным буфером.

Вот такой простой пример, почему лучше не пользоваться строкой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "Hello, End of line!";
    const char *str2 = "Hello!";
        
    std::strcpy(&str1[0], str2); // C++17 - можно str.data()
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
}
```

strcpy() копирует терминирующий символ, не так ли? Строка str1 имела длину больше чем новая строка, значит все в порядке и вывод будет "Hello!"?

Отнюдь, скорее всего вывод будет таким:

> Hello!End of line!

Длина строки осталась прежней, `length()` вернет `19`. Даже  параноидальное `std::memcpy(&str1[0], str2, strlen(str2)+1);` не поможет. Как видно, ноль "съел" пробел, но вся подсистема игнорирует наличие нулевого символа.

`std::string` не нуль-терминированная строка и вовод в данном случае  осуществляется не с использованием символа-терминатора. Это только `data()` гарантированно возвращает указатель на нуль-терминированную последовательность если `CharT` является `char`. Как `string` отслеживает свою длину, одному `string`-у известно. В данном случае

```
`str1.resize(strlen(str2));`
```

исправит положение?..  Получается что мы точно должны знать сколько символов было записано и обновить состояние "буфера" чтобы его отобразить корректно.

```
    std::string str1;
    const char *str2 = "Hello!";
        
    str1.resize(strlen(str2));  // так можно?
    std::strcpy(str1.data(), str2); 
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
```

Можно так? Вроде можно.. постойте, а куда в данном случае `strcpy` ноль пишет?  Конечно, может и не упасть, если строка выделила больше памяти. `str1.resize(strlen(str2)+1)` в данном случае менее рискованно, хотя тоже неправильно, ноль станет частью строки.

```
    str1.resize(strlen(str2));  
    std::memcpy(str1.data(), str2);
```

Comment: Начиная с C++11, std::string гарантированно является непрерывным буфером в памяти, так что можно без ограничений писать в std::string::data()

Comment: Спасибо........

Comment: Изменил boost::asio::buffer(&req+readedByte,128) ->boost::asio::buffer(req.data()+readedByte,128)  тот же Segmentation fault

Comment: @user431783 `К тому же строку нельзя использовать для записи напрямую` я специально оговорил это. а) До с++17 `.data()` предназначен для чтения, после c++17  можно спользовать но предварительно надо выделить память с помощью `reserve()` и не все ранние реализации поддержат.

Comment: @gbg после с++17. c++11 оговорил непрерывность ради коснтрукции `&str[i]`. До 17 этот буфер мог показывать на копию   и вообще гарантировалася только как `const CharT* data() const;`.

Comment: В таком случае, можно пользоваться этой конструкцией.

Comment: @gdg  как ни смешно, согласно Страустропу, это не рекомендуется делать с целью записи. Из-за возможности нарушить обращение к псевдонимам. Тот оператор с формальной точки зрения возвращает ссылку на отдельный символ. Практически все источники включая разработчиков стандарта  рекомендуют использовать неинизиализируемый вектор или выделять буфер другим способом. Преобразование данных в строку может быть нетривиальной задачей если это не однобайтные символы.

Comment: Поправочка, надо использовать resize(), не reserve(). Размер выделенного пространтства и длина строки не связаны между собой. Записть 100 байт в строку длиной 0 не делает длину строки равной 100.

Comment: Спасибо, всем кто помог, столько всего нового про строки узнал

Comment: Представляете теперь все адекватно работает)

Comment: Снова полюбил С++